# Regex in Java with method matches

Tags: java, regex

I don't understand why the output is `false` in this case:

```
public class Enhanced {
    static String[] input = {"A","B","C"};
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(input[0].matches("^[RK]"));
    }
}
```

I thought it would be `true` because 'A' is neither 'R' nor 'K'.

Answer (score 6):

```
^[RK]
```

**^** assert position at start of the string

**[RK]** matches letter R and K

You probably want to try this :

```
[^RK]
```

**[^RK]** matches a single character other than R or K